# How can i get pass the loading screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I did `console.log('check')` in `componentDidMount()` and it worked in the console.so I think there must be something wrong in the `fetch()`

What am I missing?

```js
class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            robots: [],
            searchfield: ''
        } 
    }       
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response=> response.json()) 
        .then(users =>this.setState({ robot: users}));
    } 
    render(){
            const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robots =>{
            return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase())
        })

        if (this.state.robots.length ===0){
            return <h1>Loading</h1>//loading screen
        } else {

        return(
      <div className='tc'>
            <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
            <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange} />
            <CardList robots={filteredRobots}/> 
          </div>
        );
    }
}

}


export default App;
```

thank you

Comment: When you are calling setState, you have ```robot: users``` instead of ```robots:users```

Comment: ^^ e.g., it's just a typo.

Comment: You do have a problem with the `fetch`, though; actually, two of them: You're not checking for failure, and not handling errors. Not checking for failure is **amazingly** common, so common I [wrote up the problem](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog. In the first `then` handler, you need to check `response.ok`. (And of course, add a `.catch`.)

Comment: I do see one small logic error, though: What if the `fetch` successfully returns zero robots? Suggest using `null` rather than `[]` to represent the loading state.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your state, you're initializing your state as robots, not robot like so:

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        robots: [], <- here
        searchfield: ''
    }
```

Then in your setState you are using robot like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response=> response.json()) 
    .then(users =>this.setState({ robot: users})); <- here
```

Just change this to `robots: users`

Just a small typo...

Of course, you can clean it up a little and just do:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response=> response.json()) 
    .then(robots =>this.setState({ robots}));
```

That will work too

Comment: Typos don't get *answers*, they get comments (and [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53221499/how-can-i-get-pass-the-loading-screen#comment93329900_53221499) was made long ago) and close votes.

Comment: Ah, ok... duly noted... Just trying to be helpful to a first timer and give a clear explanation that's all...

Comment: The problem is, it isn't helpful; if two people do it, the OP can't delete the question. If someone upvotes it, the OP can't delete the question. The comment that was already there was already helpful.